# query customer retention over range

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to find the best way to accomplish the following.

- Get the beginning customer count, which carries from the previous day
- Get New Customer count
- Get the number of Customers who have not come in since the prior month
- Get the number of Customers who have come back after lapsing
- Get the number of total customers

The following example

| Customer ID | Store ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 1/2/22 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 3/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 3/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1 | 3/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1 | 4/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 4 | 1 | 4/2/22 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 4/2/22 | 1.00 |

The result would be

| Date | Store | Beginning | New | Dropped | Returned | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/22 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1/2/22 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/2/22 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/2/22 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/2/22 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/2/22 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 4/2/22 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 4/2/22 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I kind of have a query, but it's not getting the right results

```
WITH customerset AS (
    SELECT
        location_id,
        date,
        array_agg(DISTINCT customer_id 
                  ORDER BY customer_id ASC) 
                  AS customer_ids
    FROM customer_orders
    GROUP BY
        location_id,
        date
)
SELECT
    cset.location_id,
    cset.date,
    array_length(cset2.customer_ids, 1) AS beginning,
    array_length((past2.customer_ids - cset.customer_ids), 1) AS dropped,
    array_length((cset.customer_ids - past2.customer_ids), 1) AS returned
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ords.location_id,
        ords.date,
        array_agg(DISTINCT ords.customer_id 
                  ORDER BY ords.customer_id ASC) 
                  AS customers_id
    FROM customer_orders ords
    GROUP BY
        ords.location_id,
        ords.date
    ) cset
JOIN
    customerset cset2 
     ON cset.date - '1 month'::interval = cset2.date
    AND cset2.location_id = cset.location_id
GROUP BY
    cset.location_id,
    cset.date,
    cset2.customer_ids,
    cset.customer_ids
ORDER BY
    cset.date ASC
```